# How to negate a subsetting argument

Tags: r, null, arguments, subset, t-test

I am writing a function that does a t test on a dataframe, subsetting the data according to the arguments I defined. Here is a working example using the mtcars data:

```
testfunc <- function(dfrm, varq, factor, gear = FALSE,
                     am = FALSE, carb = FALSE){
  # Subset the data according to the arguments:
  subsetdfrm <- dfrm[which((dfrm[,"gear"] %in% gear) & 
                             (dfrm[,"am"] %in% am) & 
                             (dfrm[,"carb"] %in% carb)),]

  # Grab the groups to be compared according to arguments:
  factorbinary <- get(factor)

  # The t-test:
  t <- t.test(dfrm[which(dfrm[factor]==factorbinary[1]), varq], 
              dfrm[which(dfrm[factor]==factorbinary[2]), varq],
              data = subsetdfrm)
  print(t)
}
```

Here is the function in action, comparing cars with 3 gears vs cars with 4 gears, looking at automatic (am=0) cars with 2 to 4 carburetors:

```
testfunc(mtcars, "mpg", "gear", gear = c(3,4), am = 0, carb = c(2:4))
```

Note that I defined the defaults of the arguments as "FALSE". What I want is to find a default value for these arguments that automatically negates the subsetting, meaning that all values are included.
My own best solution was to add if() clauses for each of the arguments at the beginning of the function as such:

```
if(carb == FALSE){gear <- unique(dfrm$gear)}
if(am == FALSE){am <- unique(dfrm$am)}
if(carb == FALSE){carb <- unique(dfrm$carb)}
```

This will become difficult to manage once the number of parameters increases.
Is there a default value I can set my arguments to, that will negate the subset?

I imagine something that is equivalent to the opposite of a NULL object: A "not-NULL", or a wildcard object that is simply equal to everything. If not, could I modify my code to make use of the NULL object in the subsetting step?

Searches with keywords "all", "any" and "subset" typically link to pages referring to the functions all() and any() and didn't get me any further. I would appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: If you have a vector of row indices (like `which` returns), you can negate them with `-`, selecting the complement. See https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html

Comment: Oh, I see you mean to *not* subset. For that, you can just write `gear = unique(dfrm$gear)` inside the `function(...)` part. Thanks to R's lazy evaluation, it will only evaluate this term when it is needed inside the function.

Comment: Which module are we looking at? It is a very long page, maybe I can ctrl-F a keyword that takes me to the section you are referring to?

Comment: I was referring to the "index vectors" section, sorry. But it's not relevant considering your notion of "negating" is not what I assumed.

Comment: I never considered putting `gear = unique(dfrm$gear)` in the arguments, I feel like this is exactly the solution I need!

Comment: You can write up your own solution as an answer below when you've got it all figured out.

Comment: I am testing it on my original code, which is tricky because instead of `dfrm`, I have a file path that is to be imported by `read.csv()`. It seems to be working fine, but I will throw some examples at it to see what it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Frank's contribution in the comments, here is a working solution:

```
testfunc <- function(dfrm, varq, factor, gear = unique(dfrm$gear),
                     am = unique(dfrm$am), carb = unique(dfrm$carb)){
  # Subset the data according to the arguments:
  subsetdfrm <- dfrm[which((dfrm[,"gear"] %in% gear) & 
                             (dfrm[,"am"] %in% am) & 
                             (dfrm[,"carb"] %in% carb)),]

  # Grab the groups to be compared according to arguments:
  factorbinary <- get(factor)

  # The t-test:
  t <- t.test(dfrm[which(dfrm[factor]==factorbinary[1]), varq], 
              dfrm[which(dfrm[factor]==factorbinary[2]), varq],
              data = subsetdfrm)
  print(t)
}
```

In my original code, instead of `dfrm`, I have a filepath that gets imported as `dfrm` by `read.csv()`. The function seems to have no problem handling the fact that "dfrm" being referred to in the arguments appears later in the course.